# Java defining multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

I am defining an array like so: `int [][] intervals = new int[10][10];` **BUT** my array will have to have different dimensions, depending on who calls the function in which this array is defined.

I wanted to try and do something like this: `int [][] intervals = new int[][];` but it says *"Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer"*

I also tried `int [][] intervals = null`, but afterwards when i try and do `intervals[3][4] = 10` it gives exception;

So how can i accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking for an array that changes size dynamically at runtime? That is a `List<Integer>`.  To simulate a two-dimensional array use `List<List<Integer>>` i.e. a list containing lists of Integer.

Comment: The first thing you tried seems to be right. maybe you mixed that array indexes start with 0 ?

Comment: Uh yeah...something like that...i don't know the dimension of the array from the beginning, so i don't want to define a huge array just for 2 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to think of a multi-dimension array as an *array of arrays*

It's not exactly like that inside the JVM, but that's the best mental model to work with for these sorts of questions.

So, if you have

```
int [][] intervals = null;
```

then your *outer-array* is null, and can later be initialised with

```
int size = 10;
intervals = new int[size][];
```

Which creates an array of `int[]`, but in that case each of the 10 *inner-arrays* are null.

If you want them all to be the same size (e.g. an 10 x 5 array) then do something like:

```
int size1 = 10;
int size2 = 5;
intervals = new int[size1][size2];
```

But if you want them to be different sizes then do something like:

```
int size = 10;
intervals = new int[size][];
intervals[0] = new int[5];
intervals[1] = new int[4];
// etc...
```

But all of these assume that you know how big you want your array to be before you start filling it.
If you don't know that, then you want to use a `List` instead - have a look at `ArrayList`.

**Edit**
I've just seen in your comment that this latter case is what you want, so ...

Try something like:

```
List< List<Integer> > list = new ArrayList< List<Integer> >();


for(int i=0; i<10; i++) // You would loop over whatever input you're processing
{                       //  but I don't know what you're doing in that part of you code
                        //  so I'll just do it 10 times.

    List<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList< Integer >();

    innerList.add( 1 );
    innerList.add( 2 );
    innerList.add( 3 );

    // etc.

    list.add( innerList );
}
```

Alternatively, you could have:

- `List< int[] >` which would mean using a List for the outside collection, but an array for the inner collection, if you know how long your inner collection is going to be.
- `List<Integer>[]` which uses an array for the outer  collection, and a list for the inner collection.

It really depends on exactly how your code needs to work.

Answer (score 4):

When creating a multidimensional array in Java, you have to specify at least the dimension of the outermost array.  In your case, if you want all the arrays to be of a different size, you will still need to specify how many arrays you need at all.  For example, if you need six arrays, you could say

```
int [][] intervals = new int[6][];
```

You could then fill them in like this:

```
intervals[0] = new int[137];
intervals[1] = new int[42];
/* ... */
```

If you don't know in advance how many arrays you'll need, you might want to consider using an `ArrayList<int[]>` to explicitly add in new arrays.  For example:

```
ArrayList<int[]> intervals = new ArrayList<int[]>();
intervals.add(new int[137]);
intervals.add(new int[42]);
/* ... */
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great...i know the number of the columns (it's 3 every time), but in this case i'll just consider it on it's side...transposed or whatever it's called.. Thanks i think this will help ;)

Comment: @AndreiBogdan If you know how big the outside collection is (columns in your case) then you might want to use `ArrayList<Integer>[]` instead. That makes it an array of lists (where templatetypedef's solution is a list of arrays).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allocate elements in array dynamically, may be you should consider [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
ArrayList< ArrayList< int > > array = new ArrayList< ArrayList< int > >();
array.add( new ArrayList< int >() );
array.get( 0 ).add( 1 );
array.get( 0 ).add( 2 );
array.add( new ArrayList< int >() );
array.get( 1 ).add( 3 );
```

Comment: aham... but i really need to use int[][] :) Otherwise I would have used array lists :)